# Variadic Templated Factory Function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm looking to create a "factory function" for a mathematical Vector class that is templated for size and type.  Here is the declaration of the class:

```
template<class T, std::size_t n>
class Vector {
  std::array<T, n> elements;

public:
  Vector();
  explicit Vector(std::array<T, n>& elements_);
  explicit Vector(const Vector<T, n>& v);
  explicit Vector(Vector<T, n>&& v);
  ~Vector() noexcept = default;
  Vector<T, n>& operator =(const Vector<T, n>& v);
  Vector<T, n>& operator =(Vector<T, n>&& v);
  T& operator [](std::size_t i);
};
```

The idea is that it is annoying to have to first create an array and then make a vector from it.  I want a variadic function called `make_vector` that takes `n` arguments of the same type `T` and returns a vector of that type and size.  Here is my attempt:

```
  template<class T, class... Ts>
  Vector<T, sizeof...(Ts) + 1> make_vector(T v1, Ts... args) {
    const std::size_t sz = sizeof...(Ts) + 1;
    std::array<T, sz> vals = {v1, args...};
    return Vector<T, sz>{vals};
  }
```

However, I get the following bewildering errors:

```
In file included from main.cpp:6:
In file included from ./oglmath.hpp:3:
In file included from ./vector.hpp:79:
./vector.tpp:14:31: warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject
      [-Wmissing-braces]
    std::array<T, sz> vals = {v1, args...};
                              ^~~~~~~~
                              {       }
main.cpp:32:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'ogl::make_vector<float, float, float>' requested here
  vertices[0] = make_vector(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
                ^
In file included from main.cpp:6:
In file included from ./oglmath.hpp:3:
In file included from ./vector.hpp:79:
./vector.tpp:15:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Vector<float,
      sizeof...(Ts) + 1>'
    return Vector<T, sz>{vals};
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./vector.hpp:13:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1
      was provided
    Vector();
    ^
In file included from main.cpp:6:
In file included from ./oglmath.hpp:3:
In file included from ./vector.hpp:79:
./vector.tpp:42:12: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Vector<[2 * ...]>' cannot
      bind to a temporary of type 'Vector<[2 * ...]>'
    return Vector<T, n>(v);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:32:15: note: in instantiation of member function 'ogl::Vector<float,
      3>::operator=' requested here
  vertices[0] = make_vector(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
              ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

Really?  The only constructor it can find is the trivial one?  What's going on!?  I totally expected this to fail in a weird way if I tried to use different types in my `Ts`, but I was careful to make them all floats!  Also, why is it getting angry at my initialization of my `std::array`?  I tried adding the bracers, and it *errored* instead of warned.

Comment: You mean `Vector<T, sizeof...(Ts) + 1> make_vector(T v, Ts... args) {`, right? There are other similar typos. Seems to be a question typo otherwise your errors would be different. Post your _actual_ [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mvce), not something with unknown numbers of unrelated & unreported extra bugs.

Comment: fixed the issue raised by @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: Also an extra `explicit` and an `...args` instead of `args...`. With your unrelated typos fixed, I can basically get this working (modulo missing ctor definitions): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbe4274c73ab0936 Again I want to make clear that these issues resulted in _completely_ different messages than shown in your question (well aside from one)

Comment: It is very important to post an example that actually generates the errors you are having a problem with.  You clearly do not understand what is going wrong, or you wouldn't be asking here: what you can do is make your code minimal, yet produce an error you don't understand, and then ask about that minimal code here (with background information about it).  If you post a summary of your code and/or errors, you can easily eliminate the part of your code that actually causes the error, introduce other errors, or otherwise confuse the ability of people to help you.

Comment: Actually, it turns out the fix was to remove the explicit on the copy constructor, as @LightnessRacesinOrbit said.  I have no idea why this fixed the issue.  Nothing in the error suggested this was the problem.  although I appreciate the concern of Yakk, I did already fix the code to match what I actually had.

Comment: That's literally why you should post a testcase, though. _Because_ you don't know. Basic logic!

Comment: "`return Vector<T, sz>{vals};`" does not match your error message line of "`return Vector<T, n>(v);`".  You do not include code to invoke `make_vector` to generate the errors in question, my attempts to take your code and invoke `make_vector` generated structurally different errors.  Basically, the code posted does not match the errors in a few ways.  This diminishes the value of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't see your usage but we can tell that, in several places, your copy-initialisations rely on implicit conversion, where no such conversion is available.

`explicit` on a copy ctor is unusual; don't think I've ever seen a case in which it's desirable.

**Remove `explicit` from the copy ctor.**

Comment: An `explicit` copy ctor, and non-explicit move ctor, could be useful: it blocks implicit copies (which could be expensive), but allows it if you explicitly copy it, then move the value into the target (which often can be elided).